How to move a git repository to the start of another git repo history
I need to do a PR to a repo that has very few fies. I developed most of my code in another unrelated repo, now I want to do a PR in github retaining my commit history, though I was able to make a fork and rebase allowing unrelated history the resulting branch cannot be merged because according to github the two branches have nothing in common. My idea was to push the few commit of the original repo into the initial history of my repo and then trick GitHub into thinking they had something in common


add the repo with your commits as the another remote and checkout your branch (let's call it my_branch)
checkout main from the main repo
use git merge --allow-unrelated-histories my_branch to merge the my_branch into the main.
you will get the merge commit looks like this

create pull request as usual.

